# php show notice within that interval dates

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In php I want to show a message in the page within the activated dates means the date from and till date will selected by the admin and within those selected days the message will be shown in the page. For date picking I have used [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I have made my database like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messagebox` (
  `message_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`message_id`))
    ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'))
```

My form for admin is looking like this

```
<form id="formID"  method="post"  action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label>Message</label>
            <div class="margin-form"><input class="text-input" type="text"  name="message" id="message" value=""/></div>
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <div class="margin-form"><input class="text-input" type="text"  name="start_date" id="start_date" value=""/> </div>
            <label>End Date</label>
            <div class="margin-form"><input class="text-input" type="text"  name="end_date" id="end_date" value=""/> </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_announcement" class="button"  value="Save"/>
            </div>
          </form>
```

For inserting data my code goes

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_announcement'])) {
            'INSERT INTO `messagebox` (`message_id`,`message`,`start_date`,`end_date`) VALUES ("","'.$message.'","'.$start_date.'","'.$end_date.'") ';
          }
          echo "Settings updated successfully";
          else {
          echo "You have some errors";
          }
```

Here I can see the data has been inserted into database.
          Now in the view page I am fetching the data.

```
$sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messagebox") or die(mysql_error());
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)){
          $message_details = $row['message'].;
            echo $message_details;
          }
```

Here I have got all the message but I want to show only the message which has been set within that time format(from start_date to end_date).After end date has been crossed then the message will be deactivated. So can some one kindly tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some method for grab start date and end date in view page, with that assumption you have to add where clause to select messages which are fall between that date range. But you haven't field for the date of message inserted. You have to add that to the table then you can use `BETWEEN` operator. So the query will be like this

`SELECT * FROM messagebox
WHERE dateinserted BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date;`

`$start_date` and `$end_date` should be strings with proper date formatting.